# OWL: restrict property value to a numeric string

Tags: string, rdf, numeric, owl

In my database I have things with string properties. Some of the property values match numeric strings (only contain digits). I'd like to give these things a special type (a subtype of what they are). Is such a thing possible in OWL?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need are `Datatype Restrictions` in combination with `xsd:pattern`.

The following axiom is from [OWL 2 Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/) ...

```
:Teenager  rdfs:subClassOf
       [ rdf:type             owl:Restriction ;
         owl:onProperty       :hasAge ;
         owl:someValuesFrom   
          [ rdf:type             rdfs:Datatype ;
            owl:onDatatype       xsd:integer ;
            owl:withRestrictions (  [ xsd:minExclusive     "12"^^xsd:integer ]
                                    [ xsd:maxInclusive     "19"^^xsd:integer ]
            )
          ]
       ] .
```

... and if you shift it a bit with `xsd:pattern` we can have something like ...

```
:YourClass  rdfs:subClassOf
       [ rdf:type             owl:Restriction ;
         owl:onProperty       :yourHasNumericProperty ;
         owl:someValuesFrom   
          [ rdf:type             rdfs:Datatype ;
            owl:onDatatype       xsd:integer ;
            owl:withRestrictions  ([xsd:pattern "E[1-9][0-9]*"])
          ]
       ] .
```

With `xsd:pattern` you can do Datatype Restriction based on regular expressions.

I hope this gives you some directions.

Comment: Hm, that does not work for me for some reason. But I import the sub class from another file as the super class and have problems getting any instances even if I do not add any restrictions. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Is actually something you can do in RDF. For any literal in RDF you can specify the type with something like this (in turtle/RDF) ...

```
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
:x :myDataTypeProperty "123"^^xsd:integer .
:y :myDataTypeProperty "some string"^^xsd:string .
:z :myDataTypeProperty "2004-12-06"^^xsd:date .
```

Same example in RDF/XML

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns="http://www.foo.bar.com#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.foo.bar.com#x">
    <myDataTypeProperty rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">123</myDataTypeProperty>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.foo.bar.com#y">
    <myDataTypeProperty rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">some string</myDataTypeProperty>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.foo.bar.com#z">
    <myDataTypeProperty rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2004-12-06</myDataTypeProperty>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

In the [XMLSchema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#) (XSD) spec you can find out all the supported datatypes. But be sure that you only use the ones mentioned in the [SPARQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/)

You could mint your own data types if you wanted and have something like:

```
:x :myDataTypeProperty "123"^^ns:MyClassificationScheme .
```

And you could go further and say that ...

```
ns:MyClassificationScheme rdfs:subClassOf xsd:integer .
```

When you issue SPARQL query against data you can specify the type when you issue apply filters, like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
   ?person :born ?birthDate .
   FILTER ( ?birthDate > "2005-02-28"^^xsd:date ) .
}
```

I hope this answered your question.

**Edited**

As panzi mentioned my answer was going in the wrong direcction. I leave it anyway.

Comment: I know that but it isn't what I want. I have a `xsd:string` datatype property that is already filled with values in my database. SOME of these values happen to match integers. I'd like resources witch such properties to be automatically of some special sub-class. It would be more handy than a `FILTER REGEX` in the query (but such a query would also be ok, just not as handy). Basically I want a regular expression (or "type conversion to `xsd:integer` supporting string") based value restriction.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I think I completelly misunderstood your question. I've added a different answer ..